# Exception in Deserialize xml to c# object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

In my application, i have serialized c# object to xml and passed xml to API to generate data and got the reponse  xml in return as  expected as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SaveLockResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.easy2access.no/webservice/types">
<Data xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
<Header>New lock was created</Header>
<Message>A lock with serialnumber [23-215-038-028476] was successfully created for customer [28242].</Message>
<Status>Success</Status>
<Lock xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Easy2Access.Engine.Engine.Types">
<d2p1:CustomerNumber>28242</d2p1:CustomerNumber>
<d2p1:Description>String</d2p1:Description>
<d2p1:G3LockId>0</d2p1:G3LockId>
<d2p1:LockId>28158</d2p1:LockId>
<d2p1:LockType>G2</d2p1:LockType>
<d2p1:MultiCode>String</d2p1:MultiCode>
<d2p1:OnetimeCode>String</d2p1:OnetimeCode>
<d2p1:SerialNumber>23-33-44-02846</d2p1:SerialNumber>
</Lock>
</SaveLockResponse>
```

Now i want this to be converted back to c# object, And i follow the below code,

```
public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
{

    T result;

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
    }


    return result;
}
```

When i call this method i will get error as below,
There is an error in XML document (1, 40).And inner exception as
 {"http://www.easy2access.no/webservice/types'> was not expected."}

Any suggesions most welcome!.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Can you share code for Class for which you are trying the deserialization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Deserialize XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889399/cant-deserialize-xml)

Comment: VERY possible :)   see: "Add the namespace"

Comment: To be more precise: Try adding `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.easy2access.no/webservice/types")]` to your class.